# Getting error on jar installation

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=tiles-api-2.2.1.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.tiles -DartifactId=tiles-api -Dversion=2.2.1 -Dpackaging=jar

I am writing this on console  but getting build failed error.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: failed to execute goal

Comment: Can you add the output of the same command with `-e` added?

Comment: repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 not authorized by proxy

Comment: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 url is trying to access but when i am opening this geting some error.

Comment: It seems that you are behind a proxy server which doesn't allow connection to the Maven repository.

Comment: @AndréStannek r u able to open above url???please try once.

Comment: @Rahulray yes, it's the default Maven central repository. Something really must be blocking it in your network.

Comment: @AndréStannek Thank u very much boss I got It .it was not working because my proxy password was changed and I was not updated it in Settings.xml..............Thanks a ton frnd.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your `maven` command with these `flags`

`-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=<proxy host> -DproxyPort=<proxy port>`